# I want to concatenate a file name with a timestamp

Tags: azure

I use azure Data Factory activity get metadata to get all files and the ForEachFile. In the ForEachFile activity I have a copy activity that copy each file to a new container. This works but I must concatenate a timestamp to each file. In Pipeline expression builder I have a @dataset().Filename. This Filename is defined as a parameter on the dataset level. So in the dataset level for the copy activity I have these two
dataset properties
Filename    @item().name
Now         @pipeline().TriggerTime
I have tried this @concat(dataset().Filename,dataset().Now) in the Pipeline expression builder This doesn't work because I get the following error Message=The required Blob is missing.
So I mean this construction @concat(dataset().Filename,dataset().Now) should work.
But for some reason the data factory can't concatenate a time stamp to each file when looping througn foreachfile. But if I just use @dataset().Filename the file is copied to the directory specified in the sink

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the value that you have passed in dataset parameter `dataset().Now`

Comment: Where are you giving the expression `@concat(dataset().Filename,dataset().Now)`? - in source dataset or sink dataset?

Comment: I followed this one and now it works https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53406.azure-data-factory-dynamically-add-timestamp-in-copied-filename.aspx

Comment: If you found answer, post that as an answer which would help the community while facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `utcnow()` function in the expression of the file path, in order to add the date to the file name.

**Expression**

`@concat(dataset().Filename,'_', formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))`

This expression is given and tested in set variable activity.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]